# A text for virtual environments seminar

Tags: reference-request, books, graphics, computer-games, hci

What is a good textbook for a seminar about

- virtual environments,  virtual worlds,  augmented reality  and
  similar topics?

The seminar is at the graduate studies level and is supposed to give introduction to virtual environments, technologies and applications as well as  current research directions.

A creative commons license and availability online would be a plus.

Here are my own results after some search:

- [Augmented Reality](http://www.intechopen.com/books/augmented-reality) - open access book at Intechopen

I was suggested these books (no online access) at another source (ResearchGate):

- "Virtual Reality Technology" (Grigore C. Burdea, Philippe Coiffet)
- "Understanding Virtual Reality: Interface, Application, and Design" (William R. Sherman, Alan B. Craig)
- "Developing Virtual Reality Applications:Foundations of Effective Design" (Alan Craig , William R. Sherman)
- "Stepping into Virtual Reality " (Mario Gutierrez, F. Vexo, Daniel Thalmann)

In your answer please comment, why do you suggest a particular source and why it is fundamental or current in the field.

Comment: Have you tried googling?

Comment: Googling is good, but there are many hits, and I did no see CC licensed text. Also, I would value the input from this community, with the emphasis on WHY this particular book is relevant and current.

Comment: In that case, you could list things you found and (dis)liked so people can see what you are after, and give feedback to the found ones.